# Why does F# not have built-in apply, map, and bind functions?

Tags: f#

Why does F# not have built-in apply, map, and bind functions for types such as 'Result' and 'Async'?

Comment: The "why" is a language design decision, probably towards simplicity and ease adoption from C# developer. Ask Don Syme on Twitter @dsymetweets.

Comment: BTW, do you know [FSharpPlus](https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpPlus/) ? It should offer what you are looking for in F#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not much of a reason other than a concrete proposal for the full set of `Result` functions simply wasn't added: https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-design/issues/49#issuecomment-206822451

There's already a `bind` and `map` function for `Result`, so in this case it's just a matter of `apply` being added for you. But as you'll quickly find if you make a proposal, there's a broader set of functionality to consider.